# How to fix Google prettify handling of HTML escape sequences

Tags: javascript, html, pretty-print, google-code-prettify

[google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) handles HTML escapes in code blocks by 'prettifying' the escape characters themselves, rather the escaped sequence. For example the:

original HTML `<code class="prettyprint lang-sql"> ... &gt; ... </code>` gets prettified into:

```
<span class="pun">&amp;</span><span class="pln">gt</span><span class="pun">;</span>
```

with obvious wrong rendering. I can't return unescaped HTML inside `<code>` as is not from trusted source and can be used as an XSS vector.

My question is if there is is any way to coerce google-pretty-print into doing the right thing and consider the content of `<code>` as HTML (escaped), not as raw text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is if there is is any way to coerce google-pretty-print into doing the right thing and consider the content of `<code>` as HTML (escaped), not as raw text.

It should, and it does.  The [C example](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html#C) demonstrates this where

```
#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;
```

is prettified to

```
<span class="pln">
</span><span class="com">#include</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="str">&lt;stdio.h&gt;</span><span class="pln">
```

and I pasted your example code into the test page and got

```
<span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">...</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">&gt;</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="pun">...</span><span class="pln"> </span>
```

I think your problem is probably a result of some other layer.  I would look into any content management system, templates, or blog publishing software that sees your HTML before the browser.

Comment: You 're right, turns out for that particular case the HTML served was escaped twice.